# SignInWithAppleButton not found in scope (SwiftUI 2)

Tags: xcode, swiftui, sign-in-with-apple

I'm implementing Sign In With Apple in a SwiftUI application (iOS 14, SwiftUI 2). I'm importing the AuthenticationServices framework. The app build successfully, and can run on an iOS device or simulator. But I cannot preview the view in the Preview / Canvas (it would be easier to design the view).

```
Cannot find 'SignInWithAppleButton' in scope
```

Any idea why?
Thanks
Axel

PS: Xcode 12 beta 6, macOS Big Sur beta 5

Comment: Is this still a problem for you? I'm on the Xcode 12 stable (Version 12.0.1 (12A7300)) and this seems to be resolved.

Comment: The latest version of Xcode solved this issue.

Answer (score 20):

The namespace of `SignInWithAppleButton` has moved from `SwiftUI` to `AuthenticationServices` since beta 6. Just `import AuthenticationServices`.